# Find department counts using group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find counts of buildings exist in a department so I use the query below

```
  select sil.Name, Count((select * from Common.Building where TypeCode=10012)), Count((select * from Common.Building where TypeCode=98)) from Common.Building ok
  join Skrs.Department sil on ok.DepartmentId=sil.Id
  group by sil.Name
```

here is the sql error msg:

> "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery"

how can I retrieve the data?

EDITED: sample data:

Common.Buildings

```
DepartmentID    Name
35              Kurum Alt Birimleri
35              VEREM SAVAŞ DİSPANSERİ
6               DİĞER
5               SAĞLIK OCAĞI
```

Skrs.Department

```
Id  Adi
1   ADANA
2   ADIYAMAN
3   AFYONKARAHİSAR
4   AĞRI
5   AMASYA
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want something like this:

```
select sil.Name,
       sum(case when b.TypeCode = 10012 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when b.TypeCode = 98 then 1 else 0 end)
from Common.Building b join
     Skrs.Department sil
     on b.DepartmentId = sil.Id
group by sil.Name;
```